# How to remove an item from an array in Swift after the user selects it?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hi I am trying to remove a color from an array of Colors after the user selects it. A  player have to select the right color that is showing in the background and when they select it I want it removed from the Array so it won't show again. The colors are randomized so I don't know the index of the selected color that's correct.

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @State var tempStr : [Color] = [Color.black]
 @State var randomColors : [Color] = [
 
    Color.green,
    Color.red,
    Color.yellow,
    Color.purple,
    Color.orange,
    Color.pink
]

@State var currentColor : Color = .green
@State private var correctAnswer = false
@State private var wrongAnswer = false

 var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(currentColor)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack {
            Text(correctAnswer ? "Correct!" : wrongAnswer ? "Wrong" : "")
            Text("Guess The Color")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                .foregroundColor(currentColor == .yellow ? .black : .white)
            ForEach(randomColors, id: \.self) { color in
                Button(action: {
                    checkChoice(colorChose: color)
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text(color.description)
                        .bold()
                        .autocapitalization(.words)
                        .foregroundColor(currentColor == .yellow ? .black : .white)
                })
               
            }
        }
        
            
    }
}
func checkChoice(colorChose color: Color) {
    if color.description == currentColor.description {
        correctAnswer = true
        wrongAnswer = false
        
        
        tempStr.removeAll { (str) -> Bool in
            str == color
            
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            correctAnswer = false
            currentColor = randomColors.randomElement()!
            
               }
        
    }else {
        wrongAnswer = true
        correctAnswer = false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            wrongAnswer = false
               }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the color from your colors array ..

```
func checkChoice(colorChose color: Color) {
    if color.description == currentColor.description {
        correctAnswer = true
        wrongAnswer = false
        
        // Here remove the colors
        randomColors.removeAll { color in
            color == currentColor
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :)